# How to restart a saved game?

Tags: grand-theft-auto-v

I see auto-save happening in GTA V, but how do I restart a saved game? Do I need to be logged onto Xbox LIVE? I'm currently not subscribed to Xbox LIVE.

Answer (score 1):

Loading a saved game has nothing to do with Xbox Live or being subscribed to it.

Loading a game is possible from the menu. Go to:
Start > Game > Load Game (Select storage device if you haven't already) > and then you can pick from your saved games to load.